# Freeciv runs very slow

Tags: performance, technical-issues, linux, freeciv

After some time freeciv runs very slow on my laptop, running onboard intel graphics. I'm using the gtk version on Ubuntu 10.10 and it seems like Xorg is consuming 100% CPU. I'm also running Compiz Fusion on the machine. Any advice on how to speed it up?

Comment: what does `glxinfo |grep direct` say ?

Answer (score 4):

Try to disable showing of trade routes between cities. They shown as green lines between cities.